# Allow nuget to download missing packages in Azure AppService

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Iam trying to deploy a asp.NET application with Azure AppService. But at the end it fails and the message says :

```
    error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\test.WebApp.V1\test.WebApp.V1.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d77908b55668cc" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11108.4192\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I have no experience with asp dotNet Frameworks or even C#, but i understand that it tries to download some dependencies from nuget, but did not manage.

How can i tackle this issue ? thanks

Comment: How are you deploying the application?

Comment: @MichaelJCox iam using AppService in Azure Cloud

Answer (score 1):

Based on this `D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11108.4192\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"`

I assume you are using Kudu to deploy.

Do the instructions from [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8c11aa7-4762-497a-812f-8ffd782072b5/kudu-build-not-restoring-nuget-packages?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) work?

> Go to Kudu Console for your site
>
> Go to d:\home\site\repository
>
> Run 'nuget restore' from here

Comment: unfortunately when i redeploy after entering he cmds, it keeps failing:
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Test.WebApp.V1\Test.WebApp.V1.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d77a88ff9cecc2" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11108.4192\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Comment: Have you run the `nuget restore` command in Kudu Console? I was having a similar issue and this approach worked for me. You can access the Kudu console through here `https://${project_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dotnet core, just go to the project directory, open a cmd from it and run:

```
dotnet restore
```

In case you're using dotnet framework:

Enable automatic package restore by choosing Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager, and then selecting Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio under Package Restore, then just build the solution and it will retrieve the missing packages.

More info in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Comment: unfortunately when i redeploy after entering he cmds, it keeps failing:
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Test.WebApp.V1\Test.WebApp.V1.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d77a88ff9cecc2" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11108.4192\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Comment: it's because you're trying to publish before it's ready. First you need to add the dependencies, then compile. Once it succeeds, you can publish.

Comment: here is what i did : 1) i get to the console of the project in Azure AppService, i cd to "\site\repository" and type "nuget restore", 2) i get to "deployment center and deploy".    Is the steps you mean ?

Comment: no, you need to do it through your local machine or through the ci/cd pipeline.